# Comparing features in a asp.net web application using different database methodologies

Tags: asp.net, comparison, sql-server, linq

I have a webstore which sells components (it is a academic project) which looks like [this](http://postimage.org/image/1sro3svz8/). I have developed the same web application using following database methodologies:

1. MS Sql Server with Stored procedures and sql data reader
2. LINQ to Sql
3. DB4o using LINQ (Client/Server)

What features can I compare apart from the technical and theoretical details between relational database and object oriented database ?

It is my graduate/master's thesis final project. I want the features that i want to compare to be more practical and interesting so that I can draw some concrete and meaningful conclusions rather than abstract comparisons which don't create much interest and hard for inference.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd compare performance, and scalability.  Which ones are faster?  How much load will each method bear before it simply won't be able to handle anymore data.

Which ones work better in distributed environments (such as load bearing web servers, and database farms)?

Which ones are easier to write and maintain. (Subjective)

Which of them can do the same work with the least amount of keystrokes or repetitive code writing?

These are just a few ideas.

Best wishes on your thesis.

Sincerely,
Kristofer Hoch

Comment: how can i compare performance and scalability. Are there any specific tools to do that? How can i do the testing in distributed environments ? Can you please eloborate for me ? Thanks in anticipation !!

Comment: You can go the easy way neanderthal way, and log date/time stamps, or you can used profiling software.  I've never had to do that kind of testing myself (I've always had another group do it for me), but I'm certain that there are packages available for you to use.